# How do I specify a "toolchain_identifier" when building tensorflow from source

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am building tensorflow from source in order to use the GPU version with an older card with a compute capability of 3.0.

When building, I get an error:

```
ERROR: /home/[user]/.cache/bazel/_bazel_[user]/35191c369325bea6db75133a187a58d6/external/local_config_cc/BUILD:57:1: in cc_toolchain rule @local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-k8: Error while selecting cc_toolchain: Toolchain identifier 'local' was not found, valid identifiers are [local_linux, local_darwin, local_windows]
```

I worked around this by hand editing `~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_[user]/35191c369325bea6db75133a187a58d6/external/local_config_cc/BUILD`

to change the toolchain_identifier from "local" to "local_linux" under cc_toolchain.

With that change, everything compiles. But, that seems unconventional to me.

Is there something should be specifying elsewhere so that bazel gets the identifier correct on its own?

Comment: Did you file an error log at TensorFlow GitHub repo yet? If not, please do so. I encountered the same issue and your workaround saved me. My Arch Linux (also bazel 0.19) at home compiles without issues including cuda, but our workstation had this stupid toolchain_identifier error with bazel 0.19. Workstation runs Ubuntu with CUDA9.

Answer (score 1):

open /home/[user]/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jeff/35191c369325bea6db75133a187a58d6/external/local_config_cc/BUILD with any text editor and change the line 57 as local_linux

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is related but ... I was having the same problem, tried a bunch of things that did not work, including alternating between clang and gcc, and then told configure I was using cudnn 7.2 instead of just 7 and it worked after that.

Comment: Thanks! I entered the full point release version (7.3.0.29). I'll see what happens if I enter 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in building tensorflow r1.9 for one older Nvidia GPU card. I downgraded the bazel from 0.19.1 to 0.18.1. The error was fixed in compiling.